# Perl Script for Bulk Adding Users to a Group after it Reads from a CSV Line

Tags: perl, ubuntu, scripting, xilinx

I'm attempting to bulk add users to a group using a CSV file and I'm running into a few frustrating errors that I can't seem to find online elsewhere:
  useradd: invalid shell '-d/home/jbower11' --(for all users in the list)
  Use of uninitialized value $fields[0] in concatenation (.) or string at csvreader.pl line 14,  line 6. --(for all users in the list)
  useradd: invalid shell '-d/home/' --(An additional error that pops up after the script has run.)

```
  system("useradd -gstudents -c $fields[0],$fields[1] -s -d/home/$fields[2] -m $fields[2]");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-s` option specifies the new user's default shell. You are passing `-d/home/$fields[2]` which is not a valid shell name

There is also a blank line at the end of your data file which you are not discarding

Please use the passive facilities available on the internet to diagnose your problems before resorting to personal assistance, and make an attempt to format your questions properly if you really do need help

Comment: Excellent, your fix worked. I appreciate the formatting tips. I'll keep that in mind next time.